# Anyone knows a free Drupal theme with jquery Masonry?

Tags: jquery, drupal, themes, jquery-masonry

I can not find a free drupal theme that uses  jquery [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/#install) and I tried more Masonry modules but no effect, so I hope someone knows a free Drupal theme with jquery Masonry.

Answer (score 2):

you can go with this for masonry effects

1. Bootstrap theme
2. Best Responsive theme

I used both themes with Masonry.

Download here :

https://drupal.org/project/best_responsive

https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap‎

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this one, but you can: http://fxtheme.com/themes/contour-multipurpose-creative-drupal-7-theme

Comment: it's a $50 not a free one.

Comment: sorry it's free but impossible to download - download won't star maybe it's not free